# Angular 2 http://localhost:3002/traceur 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an SPA that was on @angular RC5 which I am trying to move up to the official release.  Before the move, everything seemed to work fine in development.  No errors in the chrome debug console.

Now I have changed my package.json to:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.0.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "lodash": "^4.14.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
```

I also cleaned up a bunch of `ROUTER_PROVIDER` references, removed all multi line comments.  However now when I run my app:

```
zone.js:1274 GET http://localhost:3002/traceur 404 (Not Found)scheduleTask @ zone.js:1274ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:216Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:153(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1304send @ VM1437:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1156(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1739ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:478(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1738(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2764(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3338(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3605(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3990(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4453(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4705(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:408ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:203Zone.run @ zone.js:96(anonymous function) @ zone.js:462ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:236Zone.runTask @ zone.js:136drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:368ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:308
zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3002/traceur
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3002/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:647:29)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3002/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:236:37)
        at Zone.runTask 
(http://localhost:3002/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:136:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3002/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:304:33)
    Error loading http://localhost:3002/traceur
    Error loading http://localhost:3002/vendor/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.js as "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" from http://localhost:3002/app/main.js ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3002/traceur(…) nullconsoleError @ zone.js:355_loop_1 @ zone.js:382drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:308
zone.js:357 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3002/traceur(…)consoleError @ zone.js:357_loop_1 @ zone.js:382drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:308
13system.src.js:373 Assertion failed: loading or loaded(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:373ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:203Zone.run @ zone.js:96(anonymous function) @ zone.js:462ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:236Zone.runTask @ zone.js:136drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:368ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:308
```

I've looked through a number of posts with a similar problem, but I'm at a loss as to what is causing this?

Comment: They really do need to figure out how to give us a more detailed error report  on what is causing  this. I've had it before and it was a pain in the ___ to try fix.

Answer (score 2):

**traceur 404** is an indication that Angular is not able to find/load required thing(s) or package(s). Through your post, I can suggest you below things only.

**1)** `package.json` is not correct. Please compare it with [package.json](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) here.

**2)** `zone.js` requires higher version for Angular2.0.1.

**3)** `es6-shim": "^0.35.0"` shim is not required anymore with latest version. Remove your reference from `index.html` as well.

Other than these, there can be many other things which can cause problem. But it is hard to say as of now.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers!  I'll work through these.  In the meantime, is there any more information I can provide that might help?

Comment: No. nothing will help I guess. You need to understand that everything is module in Angular2. E.g in AppComponent if you are using HTTP service, then you have to make sure that HttpModule is imported. So there will be lot of things in your case which will be hard to identify in one go.